# How to change the datatype of the Dummy Column in a View?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

```
create or replace view ABC_VIEW(
   VEHICLEID, BRAND,
   MODEL, VEHICLE_TYPE,
   FUEL_TYPE, TRANSMISSION_TYPE,
   GEARBOX, DRIVE_TYPE,
   VEHICLE_NUMBER, PRICE, 
   "TEST Column"
) as 
  select VEHICLEID, BRAND,
         MODEL, VEHICLE_TYPE,
         FUEL_TYPE, TRANSMISSION_TYPE,
         GEARBOX, DRIVE_TYPE,
         VEHICLE_NUMBER, PRICE, 
         '' as "TEST Column" 
    from ABC;
```

By default `"Test Column"` is created as `Char(1)`. How do I change it to `Number` data Type?

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: `''` is not a number, so you cannot define it as such. Your query doesn't make sense. What number should `''` represent? Why don't you just include the number that you want instead .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for `TO_NUMBER` function.

Try this:

```
create or replace view ABC_VIEW
(VEHICLEID,BRAND,MODEL,VEHICLE_TYPE,FUEL_TYPE,TRANSMISSION_TYPE,GEARBOX,DRIVE_TYPE,VEHICLE_NUMBER,PRICE,**"TEST Column"**) 
as select  VEHICLEID,BRAND,MODEL,VEHICLE_TYPE,FUEL_TYPE,
TRANSMISSION_TYPE,GEARBOX, DRIVE_TYPE,VEHICLE_NUMBER,PRICE,TO_NUMBER('') 
 from ABC;
```

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier 
Getting This Error message

Comment: @Subbu:- Updated my answer. Please check now!

Comment: Hi Rahul Tripathi, It Worked.,. Thanks Man.,.

Answer (score 5):

Like here:

```
create or replace view v_abc as 
  select cast(null as number) test_column
    from dual;
```

Test:

```
select table_name, column_name, data_type 
  from all_tab_columns where table_name='V_ABC';

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_TYPE 
------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------
V_ABC                          TEST_COLUMN                    NUMBER
```